# Hermite Series of $x^{2m}$ , $e^{ax}$ and $e^{-ax^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following task, to show that for $-\infty < x < \infty$ :

$x^{2m} = \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}}\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{H_{2n}(x)}{(2n)!(m-n)!}$

$x^{2m+1} = \frac{(2m+1)!}{2^{2m+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{H_{2n+1}(x)}{(2n+1)!(m-n)!}$

$e^{ax} = e^{\frac{a^2}{4}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{2^nn!}H_n(x)$

$e^{-a^2x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^na^n}{2^nn!(1+a^2)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}H_{2n}(x)$

I understand that I have to express each function of the left hand as a Hermite series but I can't do so. The way I try is to substitute $H_{n}=(-1)^ne^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x^2})$ on the integral evaluating the coeffiecients but even in the first case I can't see how consecutive integrations by parts will give me the given result. Please try to work out one of the cases if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Check out this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352374514_A_GENERAL_EXPRESSION_FOR_HERMITE_EXPANSIONS_WITH_APPLICATIONS

Answer (score 0):

Use the orthogonality of the hermite polynomials: $\int_{- \infty}^\infty H_n(x)H_m(x)e^{-x^2}dx = 0(m \neq n)$. Multiply one of this functions by $H_m(x)e^{-x^2}$ and integrate.

Now you can Substitute the Definition of the Hermite polynomials and you can do partial Integration sucessively (with integrand vanishing at the boundaries):

$\int_{- \infty}^\infty H_m(x)e^{-x^2}e^{ax}dx = \int_{- \infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} 
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{ax}dx$ (every time when the differentiation is switched one obtains a factor -1). Hence $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{ax} = a^ne^{ax}$ and simply evaluate the Gaussian integral. On the right Hand side, orthogonality Relations simplify the sum.